# How do you hide an HTML element based on a series of parent elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What i am trying to accomplish is hiding all activity stream posts from one user in a feed by its data type. I am able to distinguish the users post using CSS with this structure

```
.joms-stream.joms-embedly--left.joms-js--stream > div > div > a > img[data-author="921"] {
display: none !important;
```

}

How am i able to hide the entire stream item using a series of (this.parent) in jQuery or javascript? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean if the element satisfies the selector criteria, hide the top most element?

Comment: Yes, like  .parent(img[data-author="921"]).parent(a).parent(div).parent(div).style.display="none"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by using the `.parents(selector).last()` code:

For example:

```
$("img[data-author="921"]").parents(".joms-stream.joms-embedly--left.joms-js--stream")
    .last().hide();
```

This code works because jQuery returns a list of parents from `.parent(selector)` from in most to the out most, thus using `.last()` will select the out most parent.

Or if you are sure that `.joms-stream.joms-embedly--left.joms-js--stream` won't appear twice in the nest (you should be quite sure because you are using `>`s to select), you can use the `.closest(selector)` method, which will select the closest match from the element:

```
$("img[data-author="921"]").closest(".joms-stream.joms-embedly--left.joms-js--stream")
    .hide();
```

P.S. `$(jqueryElem).hide()` is equivalent to `$(jQueryElem).style("display", "none")` or `elem.style.display = "none"` because you seem to be quite new to jQuery.

Comment: Hey, can you update the answer to $( "img[data-author='921']" )
  .closest( ".joms-stream" )
    .css( "display", "none" ); So i can award you the answer :) I just tried it and it worked like this.